# Gallery of GEF/Draw2D figures

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, draw2d, eclipse-gef

I am new to GEF/Draw2D, I've seen some tutorials on the topic, but I am wondering if any of you have seen a **gallery of all figures** which are shipped together with **GEF**? So that one can quickly see what do they look like and what's their purpose?

Comment: A similar gallery for Eclipse SWT may be found here: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no such gallery. Anyway, you can checkout draw2d examples from GIT repo. There are many of those figures.

See http://nyssen.blogspot.cz/2010/12/draw2d-examples-hidden-treasure.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the Type Hierarchy view of Eclipse to view the descendants of the Figure class. Unfortunately, it's not a graphical preview, but the class names are descriptive enough, I hope.

Comment: Sorry. That doesn't seem to help much. I know I can find all the subclasses easily, but that's far from being a gallery. Thanks awyway.